# mysql timestamp query

Tags: mysql

i need to update the php timestamp column type automatically whenever some update is done on its particular certain row. can it be done?

the format of the timestamp is "0000-00-00 00:00:00"

i also want to compare the current(system) timestamp with the value already set in the column. for example, i want to compare the current system timestamp with the DB value and if the current value is more than 10 minutes ahead of the DB value, do a certain action. how can i check this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to set `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` on the row in the DB (assuming you are using MYSQL). The other way is to insert the value of `NOW()` when you do your insert.

When you query the DB, instead of just writing `SELECT timestamp FROM...` write `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) as stamp FROM...`. This will give you it back as a UNIX time stamp. You can then compare that to the value from `time()`, and check if it's more than 600 seconds from the DB timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL function `NOW()` will always give you the current timnestamp.

This will set the `modified` field to the current timestamp:

```
UPDATE user SET realname='John Smith', modified=NOW()
```

or this will give you the records modified in the last 10 minutes.

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE modified > TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE, -10, NOW())
```

Comment: And what is the peoblem with this answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
`updated` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

Answer (score -1):

A 'timestamp column' is NOT php. THat's mysql. MySQL will, by default, auto-update the first timestamp column in any given table anytime the record is changed or inserted.

To select based on that timestamp, you'd do

```
SELECT field,field,field
FROM yourtable
WHERE (timestampfield, DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
```